# cannot render a complex React Element in order to replace a DOM element by id

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner with react so please excuse me if this question does not make sense.
I have a complex div element in the html document with an id, it looks like this:

[image: aaa]aaavote: I am comingChange My vote
Delete Me

and it was originally created from rendering a react element that was returned from a component, like this:
let content = visitors_list.map((visitor) =>

)
{content} was returned from the react component.

At some stage I need to replace that div (with id="MyDiv2") with a different content.
I have a function that creates this new "content" exactly the same way I created the original one, however, now instead of return it from the component and have react do the rendering, I need to do it manually and call:
document.getElementById("MyDiv2").innerHTML = something

I cannot just pass content as something because : component is an array of [object Object]
I cannot pass it as a json structure because JSON.stringify(content) gives me:
[{"type":"div","key":"1","ref":null,"props":{"className":"flex-no-shrink w-full md:w-1/4 md:px-3","children":{"key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"visitor":{"id":"1","name":"aaa","vote":0,"imageUrl":"http://www.stone-guitar-picks.com/stoneguitarpicksshop/images/large/GP2046_LRG.JPG"}},"_owner":null,"_store":{}}},"_owner":null,"_store":{}}]

so I tried: ReactDOM.render(content, document.getElementById("MyDiv2"))
but ReactDOM.render does nothing, infact it breaks and exists the function.

I also tried using React.createElement(content) - also did not work...

How can I solve this problem. the only solution that I found to work is forcing the refreshing of the page which I do not want to do.

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a fundamental understanding of how React works.  You should be able to achieve all of this using a few reusable components with props and state.  If it's a single page app, you should only be calling ReactDOM.render once in your root component, then conditionally changing content with child components based on state and props.

Answer (score 0):

Dont try to handle the dom manually, react does this for you!, imagine you have your component MyInput that renders an input with some characteristics that may be passed by properties as well, then you could just change your component props and react will change your component automatically. i'll try to post a hardcoded example:

```
const myComp = ({text, visible}) = return (
 <input text={text} visibility={visible}>
)
```

then, when you change your component text it will render it automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I followed what I think you meant, I made the component return {content} and I made the content changes with useState and useEffect when required and that made the DOM to change automatically.

Comment: Sounds good, keep in mind that if you change your text or visibility from the component that renders "myComp" it changes automagically.